# Can we please have some sort of API to poll for new data dump releases?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-dump, api

I'm writing an application that uses the data dump. However, in order to be effective, this application needs to be kept up to date with the latest data dump. This currently needs to be done manually.

Therefore, I request an API (something simple) that:

1. Returns a list of all data dumps
2. Include a link to the torrent file in the response
3. Update it when new data dumps come out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see

http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-overflow-data-dump

specifically the RSS feed for that account

http://www.clearbits.net/feeds/creator/146-stack-overflow-data-dump.rss

Comment: Ah, that'll work fine. Thanks for pointing the feed out.